# Google App Sync

Tags: extension, google

I recently installed Cividesk's Google App Sync extension. I did the whole setup and everything seems to work properly in CiviCRM. The Scheduled jobs are working as expected and the extension configuration page says:    OAuth authentication and secrets fully configured and working.

The problem is that I don't see the contacts in my Google account. I am currently using a free trial of the Google apps for business, can that be the problem?

[image]